# Split URL string to get each parameter value in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var url = "journey?reference=123line=A&destination=China&operator=Belbo&departure=1043&vehicle=ARC"
```

How can I split the string above so that I get each parameter's value??

Comment: @Diodeus I would like a solution that saves them all to an array and that I can use repeatedly on lots of URLs

Comment: That is a secondary issue, once you've parsed the data and created the object.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the split function to extract the parameter pairs. First trim the stuff before and including the `?`, then split the `&` and after that loop though that and split the `=`.

```
var url = "journey?reference=123line=A&destination=China&operator=Belbo&departure=1043&vehicle=ARC";

var queryparams = url.split('?')[1];

var params = queryparams.split('&');

var pair = null,
    data = [];

params.forEach(function(d) {
    pair = d.split('=');
    data.push({key: pair[0], value: pair[1]});

});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMtkr/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var myurl = "journey?reference=123&line=A&destination=China&operator=Belbo&departure=1043&vehicle=ARC";
var keyval = myurl.split('?')[1].split('&');
for(var x=0,y=keyval.length; x<y; x+=1)
console.log(keyval[x], keyval[x].split('=')[0], keyval[x].split('=')[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

to split line in JS u should use:

```
var location = location.href.split('&');
```

Comment: Instead of location.href, it would be easier to use location.search which will only return the question mark and everything after it. Then just chop off the first character using a substring.

Comment: @tomysshadow yeah! It's even better! Thanks!